# Percentage Encoding of special characters before sending it in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, urlencode, url-encoding

I need to pass special characters like #,! etc in URL to Facebook,Twitter and such social sites. For that I am replacing such characters with URL Escape Codes.

```
 return valToEncode.Replace("!", "%21").Replace("#", "%23")
   .Replace("$", "%24").Replace("&", "%26")
   .Replace("'", "%27").Replace("(", "%28")
   .Replace(")", "%29").Replace("*", "%2A");
```

It works for me, but I want to do it more efficiently.Is there any other way to escape such characters? I tried with **Server.URLEncode()** but Facebook doesn't render it.

Thanks in advance,
Priya

Answer (score 45):

You should use the **[Uri.EscapeDataString**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) method if you want to have compatibility with [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) standard, where percent-encoding is defined.

For example spaces always will be encoded as `%20` character:

```
var result = Uri.EscapeDataString("a q");
// result == "a%20q"
```

while for example usage of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` (which is by the way internally used by `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`) returns `+` character:

```
var result = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("a q") 
// result == "a+q"
```

What's more, the behavior of `Uri.EscapeDataString` is compatible with client side `encodeURIComponent` javascript method (except the case sensitivity, but RFC3986 says it is irrelevant).

Comment: It also depends on whether FB, Twitter etc. has IRI IDN parsing enabled. Twitter 1.1 for instance has this, so characters like eg. '!'  has to be encoded as well ("%21")

Answer (score 5):

For those still searching, Thomas B provided a great one-liner for this.

```
Regex.Replace(Uri.EscapeDataString(s), "[\!*\'\(\)]", Function(m) Uri.HexEscape(Convert.ToChar(m.Value(0).ToString())))
```

Found in the comments under [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853466/1175419) which also provides a sound solution to the problem.

The behavior for `Uri.EscapeDataString` changes in .Net 4.5.

> The list of reserved and unreserved characters now supports RFC 3986.

See [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=VS.110%29.aspx#core).

Also note the [specific reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) for RFC 3986. I haven't tested either function extensively nor have I taken the time to study RFC 2396 so I can only assume that Andrew and Thomas are using a subset of the reserved characters because that subset reflects the difference between RFC 2396 and RFC 3986 and the remaining characters are already handled by `Uri.EscapeDataString`.

Answer (score 3):

This code will "PercentEncode" per rfc 3986.  HttpUtility.EncodeUrl does not account for many characters ('!', '*', '(', ')') and does not upper case the hex letters following the % character.

```
public static string PercentEncode(string value)  
{  
    StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder();  
    foreach (char c in value)  
    {   
        if ((c >= 48 && c <= 57) || //0-9  
            (c >= 65 && c <= 90) || //a-z  
            (c >= 97 && c <= 122) || //A-Z                    
            (c == 45 || c == 46 || c == 95 || c == 126)) // period, hyphen, underscore, tilde  
        {  
            retval.Append(c);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            retval.AppendFormat("%{0:X2}", ((byte)c));  
        }  
    }  
    return retval.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please understand: this answer is really **bad** for two reasons: A) no formatting whatsoever - there is a lot of help to understand how to format, and even a **preview** function. Use that B) "code only answers" are discourages. Always consider having some explanations.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` or `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode` instead of forming it manually.