# Some (not all) punctuation in a tweet causes API error 32 "Could not authenticate you"

Tags: .net, twitter, twitter-oauth, urlencode

I rejoiced when I finally got some ASP.NET code talking to Twitter's API, and it performed perfectly when testing, creating tweets of any length on my account, mentioning @usernames, and even tweeting 10 times a minute to the same account.

But now I am getting HTTP status code 401 and this JSON back:
`{"errors":[{"code":32, "message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

The errors almost appeared random, until I noticed something. It seems I never used punctuation in any of my previous tests! Now, tweets with apostrophes, brackets and exclamation marks are rejected - yet commas, hyphens and question marks are fine.

The first line of this section must be my problem area:

```
Dim postBody = "media_ids=" & TwitterMediaID & "&status=" & Uri.EscapeDataString(TextOfTheTweet)
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(TwitterStatusPostURL)
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", OAuthSignature)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

I guess `Uri.EscapeDataString()` is the wrong choice of encoding, though I am very grateful to the [original author](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247336/Twitter-OAuth-authentication-using-Net) for this code because I would be nowhere without them!

This function takes in `Apotrophe' exclamation! brackets() question? fullstop. comma, colon: semicolon; hyphen-` and returns `Apotrophe'%20exclamation!%20brackets()%20question%3F%20fullstop.%20comma%2C%20colon%3A%20semicolon%3B%20hyphen-` which is clearly not what Twitter wants to see (or rather, this is something to do with OAuth?).

According to [the wonderful table in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21771206/11461) there is nothing that encodes an exclamation mark?!

I should be able to find a better function to use, by myself, but I'd love to hear exactly what the problem was here, and have reassurance that I understand which encoding functions are right for which job. This also needs to be documented for future punctuation-addled programmers.

So the question can be summarised as: **Why is this function not the right choice, and what should we use?** Thanks.

Comment: This is due to encoding and OAuth. You need to encode certain values. Check out [this page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/percent-encoding-parameters.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Twitter API documentation (as of March 2019) says I must use **RFC 3986**.

It seems the older version of dotNET that I am using doesn't support **RFC 3986** fully within `Uri.EscapeDataString()` and I would need dotNET v4.5 or above to solve that issue.

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119698/11461) says I can just make up the four missing punctuation elements myself with this one-liner:

```
Regex.Replace(Uri.EscapeDataString(s), "[\!*\'\(\)]", Function(m) Uri.HexEscape(Convert.ToChar(m.Value(0).ToString())))
```

Personally I feel comfortable with a more readable version:

```
Uri.EscapeDataString(s).Replace("!", "%21").Replace("'", "%27").Replace("(", "%28").Replace(")", "%29")
```

Comment: I've just discovered that my second code snippet is missing the asterisk. There are five punctuation symbols, not four!

Comment: How can I do this in javascript? Is there any similar function?

Comment: Yes, Javascript has a similar function `.replace(/\!/g, '%21')`