# How to URL encode strings in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, url-encoding

How can we encode a string using the URL (RFC 1738) standard in C#?

The following online tool is converting the strings using this standard http://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html

An example of the string I want to convert is `test(brackets)` and the encoded string should look like:

```
test%28brackets%29
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Encoding using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> ```
> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
> reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
> unencoded within a URL.
> ```

Neither [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) nor [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will encode those characters since the standard says the parentheses `()` can be used unencoded.

I don't know why the [URL Encoder / Decoder](http://www.freeformatter.com/url-encoder.html) you linked encodes them since it also lists them as as a character that can be used in a URL.

Comment: I m making calls to a third party API over HTTP and passing a string in the parameters. This string is UTF-8 URL encoded. My API client is written in asp.net C# where as the API host is probably written in Java. When I have characters like parenthesis/brackets () in the string parameter, UTF-8 encoder does not encode them whereas the API host encodes them in %28 and %29 and I get incorrect response. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: The API has the following reference in the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: You could maybe look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846487/how-to-get-uri-escapedatastring-to-comply-with-rfc-3986

Answer (score 27):

[`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does what you want. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry It does not work. Tried this string str = "test(brackets)"; str = Uri.EscapeDataString(str);

Comment: Strange. When I try "string result = Uri.EscapeDataString("test(brackets)");" the result is "test%28brackets%29". What value has str after EscapeDataString on your system?

Comment: The string stays the same. It does not change

Comment: The behaviour of Uri.EscapeDataString [changed with .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to include RFC 3986 characters.

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks for the info. Indeed I am targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: Tried, change from 4.0 to 4.5 in project properties does not work, new one 4.5 web app will work. A little strange.

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.EscapeDataString` will convert the string using the Uri standrards, which is not RFC 1738 conform.

RFC 1738 is an old URL standard.
I accomplished it by using [`FormUrlEncodedContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=netframework-4.8):

```cs
data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value"));

var payloadBody = await new FormUrlEncodedContent(data).ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If you don`t need a encoded URL *body* you probably need to trick arround with the key / value f.e. let the value empty.