# MSTest fails Unit Test that passes in VS 2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, encoding, mstest

I've been setting up a Cake script (C# Make) in preparation of automating our unit testing. I have the script set up and it's running the unit tests as expected except for one quirk...

One of the simpler tests is failing when MSTest attempts to execute it but it passes with flying colors when I run the test from VS 2013.

```
            [TestMethod]
        public void Field_is_XmlNode_innertext_urlencode()
        {
            // Arrange
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<field>\"'#</field>");
            var fetchedField = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("field");

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("%22%27%23", CrmHelpers.GetFetchedFieldValueAsString(fetchedField, null, true));
        }
```

Cake script section that calls MSTest.

```
Task("RunTests")
.IsDependentOn("Build")
.Does(() =>
{
    Information("TestPath {0}", "./Tests/Unit Tests/**/bin/" + configuration + "/*.UnitTests.dll");
    MSTest("./Tests/Unit Tests/**/bin/" + configuration + "/*.UnitTests.dll");
});
```

In VS2013 the value \"'# is properly encoded to %22%27%23 however when executing the test via Cake calling MSTest that same value is encoded as %22'%23.

[image]
[image]

My questions are: Why are these values encoded differently in MSTest from what I see in VS2013 when theoretically it should be running the same code?
How do I correct the issue so that MSTest runs all of my unit tests in a predictable and consistent manner?

EDIT 1: Adding requested method

```
 public static string GetFetchedFieldValueAsString(XmlNode fetchedField, string format, bool urlEncode)
    {
        var fieldValue = "";

        if (format.IsNotEmpty())
        {
            try
            {
                if (fetchedField.Attributes["date"] != null)
                {
                    var date = DateTime.Parse(fetchedField.InnerText).ToUniversalTime();
                    fieldValue = GetFormatedDateAsString(date, format);
                }
                else if (fetchedField.InnerText.IsNumeric())
                {
                    var number = float.Parse(fetchedField.InnerText);
                    fieldValue = number.ToString(format);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Ignore formating errors
            }
        }

        if (fieldValue.IsEmpty()) fieldValue = fetchedField.GetAttributeValue("name");
        if (fieldValue.IsEmpty()) fieldValue = fetchedField.GetAttributeValue("formattedvalue");
        if (fieldValue.IsEmpty() && fetchedField.Attributes["date"] != null)
        {
            var date = fetchedField.GetAttributeValue("date");
            var time = fetchedField.GetAttributeValue("time");
            if (date.IsNotEmpty()) fieldValue = date;
            if (date.IsNotEmpty() && time.IsNotEmpty()) fieldValue += " ";
            if (time.IsNotEmpty()) fieldValue += time;
        }
        if (fieldValue.IsEmpty()) fieldValue = fetchedField.InnerText;
        if (fieldValue.IsGuid()) fieldValue = fieldValue.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
        fieldValue = fieldValue.Sanitize();
        if (urlEncode) fieldValue = fieldValue.UrlComponentEncode();
        return fieldValue;
    }
```

EDIT 2: Adding requested method

```
    public static string UrlComponentEncode(this string s)
    {
        return Uri.EscapeDataString(s);
    }
```

EDIT 3: Cake Methods to get MSTest path

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the default tool path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The default tool path.</returns>
    protected override FilePath GetDefaultToolPath(MSTestSettings settings)
    {
        foreach (var version in new[] { "12.0", "11.0", "10.0" })
        {
            var path = GetToolPath(version);
            if (_fileSystem.Exist(path))
            {
                return path;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private FilePath GetToolPath(string version)
    {
        var programFiles = _environment.GetSpecialPath(SpecialPath.ProgramFilesX86);
        var root = programFiles.Combine(string.Concat("Microsoft Visual Studio ", version, "/Common7/IDE"));
        return root.CombineWithFilePath("mstest.exe");
    }
```

Comment: You'd have to show the `GetFetchedFieldValueAsString` method, since that is apparently what you are testing.

Comment: Now add the `UrlComponentEncode()` implementation, as that is the method that returns something different on your build server.

Comment: @Dirk Second method added

Comment: I once digged into that topic when answering another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013879/how-to-url-encode-strings-in-c-sharp. I found out that EscapeDataString has been changed in .NET 4.5. Maybe you target different versions with your 2 tests.

Comment: It does seem similar. It's the ' that is the problem child however I am running .NET 4.5 in VS and it works when ran from there. Maybe I don't fully understand but it seems the opposite of the expected behavior.

I'm not sure how to check what version of .NET MSTest is running against or how to configure that. I'll look into it on my own but if you have any insights into that I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: @Dirk Forcing Cake/MSBuild to build with a MSBuildToolVersion for VS 2013 and the same thing happens. According to the source code that would be the default though so that's not surprising.

Comment: Manually verified that every project is configured to run against .net 4.5

Comment: @Dirk Ok, progress! I can't seem to figure out how to make MSTest run against .NET 4.5 however I can change VS2013 to test against .NET 4.0 and when I do that I get the same error! Now I just need to figure out how to get Cake to run MSTest as 4.5...

Comment: Do you know if the mstest is run with mstest.exe or vstest.console.exe?  I haven't used cake, so I don't know which it uses.  FYI, mstest.exe is the old way to run tests and vstest.console.exe is the new way..

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you further since I'm neither using Cake nor MSTest. But at least we now know why the output is different.

Comment: @Dirk Np, thanks for helping me track down exactly what the issue was.

Comment: @JohnKoerner It's using MSTest.exe. I'll append those methods to the original post.

Comment: Call `HtmlDecode` on the string before comparing?

Comment: @JohnKoerner Does MSTest not support .NET 4.5? You said that vstest.console.exe is the new way, is that .NET 4.5+?

Comment: @Justinwilliams I don't know for sure, but you could always modify your tooling to use vstest.console.exe to see if it corrects your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just don't use Cake. Going back to a PS solution.