# REST API authentication (OAuth 1.0) using C#

Tags: c#, rest, oauth

I'm trying to connect to the Bricklink REST API using OAuth (http://apidev.bricklink.com/redmine/projects/bricklink-api/wiki/Authorization).

It should be pretty straight forward. However, I'm currently stuck and keep getting a SIGNATURE_INVALID error. My current attempt is shown below. Any suggestions?

```
        const string consumerKey = "";
        const string consumerSecret = "";
        const string tokenSecret = "";
        const string tokenValue = "";
        const string url = "https://api.bricklink.com/api/store/v1/items/part/3001";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        var timeStamp = ((int) (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
        var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timeStamp));

        var signatureBaseString = httpWebRequest.Method.ToUpper() + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + url.ToLower() + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + "oauth_consumer_key=" + consumerKey + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + "oauth_signature_method=" + "HMAC-SHA1" + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + "oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + "oauth_token=" + tokenValue + "&";
        signatureBaseString = signatureBaseString + "oauth_version=" + "1.0";
        signatureBaseString = Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureBaseString);
        Console.WriteLine(signatureBaseString);

        var signatureEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        var keyBytes = signatureEncoding.GetBytes(consumerSecret + "&" + tokenSecret);
        var signatureBaseBytes = signatureEncoding.GetBytes(signatureBaseString);
        string signatureString;
        using (var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
        {
            var hashBytes = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(signatureBaseBytes);
            signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }
        signatureString = Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureString);
        Console.WriteLine(signatureString);

        string SimpleQuote(string x) => '"' + x + '"';
        var header =
            "OAuth realm=" + SimpleQuote("") + "," +
            "oauth_consumer_key=" + SimpleQuote(consumerKey) + "," +
            "oauth_nonce=" + SimpleQuote(nonce) + "," +
            "oauth_signature_method=" + SimpleQuote("HMAC-SHA1") + "," +
            "oauth_timestamp=" + SimpleQuote(timeStamp) + "," +
            "oauth_token=" + SimpleQuote(tokenValue) + "," +
            "oauth_version=" + SimpleQuote("1.0") + "," +
            "oauth_signature= " + SimpleQuote(signatureString);
        Console.WriteLine(header);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, header);

        var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var characterSet = ((HttpWebResponse) response).CharacterSet;
        var responseEncoding = characterSet == ""
            ? Encoding.UTF8
            : Encoding.GetEncoding(characterSet ?? "utf-8");
        var responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if (responsestream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(characterSet));
        }
        using (responsestream)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responsestream, responseEncoding);
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

I know that consumerKey, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, and tokenValue are correct as I can connect using the bricklink-api (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bricklink-api) using JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

After studying https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process again, I finally got it right. Note, the Escape function is not essential I just happened to stumble upon that one while trying to make things work.

```
        const string consumerKey = "";
        const string consumerSecret = "";
        const string tokenSecret = "";
        const string tokenValue = "";
        const string url = "https://api.bricklink.com/api/store/v1/items/part/3001";

        string Escape(string s)
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846487/how-to-get-uri-escapedatastring-to-comply-with-rfc-3986
            var charsToEscape = new[] {"!", "*", "'", "(", ")"};
            var escaped = new StringBuilder(Uri.EscapeDataString(s));
            foreach (var t in charsToEscape)
            {
                escaped.Replace(t, Uri.HexEscape(t[0]));
            }
            return escaped.ToString();
        }

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        var timeStamp = ((int) (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
        var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timeStamp));

        var signatureBaseString = Escape(httpWebRequest.Method.ToUpper()) + "&";
        signatureBaseString += EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(url.ToLower()) + "&";
        signatureBaseString += EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(
            "oauth_consumer_key=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(consumerKey) + "&" +
            "oauth_nonce=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(nonce) + "&" +
            "oauth_signature_method=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986("HMAC-SHA1") + "&" +
            "oauth_timestamp=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(timeStamp) + "&" +
            "oauth_token=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(tokenValue) + "&" +
            "oauth_version=" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986("1.0"));
        Console.WriteLine(@"signatureBaseString: " + signatureBaseString);

        var key = EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(consumerSecret) + "&" + EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(tokenSecret);
        Console.WriteLine(@"key: " + key);
        var signatureEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        var keyBytes = signatureEncoding.GetBytes(key);
        var signatureBaseBytes = signatureEncoding.GetBytes(signatureBaseString);
        string signatureString;
        using (var hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
        {
            var hashBytes = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(signatureBaseBytes);
            signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }
        signatureString = EscapeUriDataStringRfc3986(signatureString);
        Console.WriteLine(@"signatureString: " + signatureString);

        string SimpleQuote(string s) => '"' + s + '"';
        var header =
            "OAuth realm=" + SimpleQuote("") + "," +
            "oauth_consumer_key=" + SimpleQuote(consumerKey) + "," +
            "oauth_nonce=" + SimpleQuote(nonce) + "," +
            "oauth_signature_method=" + SimpleQuote("HMAC-SHA1") + "," +
            "oauth_timestamp=" + SimpleQuote(timeStamp) + "," +
            "oauth_token=" + SimpleQuote(tokenValue) + "," +
            "oauth_version=" + SimpleQuote("1.0") + "," +
            "oauth_signature= " + SimpleQuote(signatureString);
        Console.WriteLine(@"header: " + header);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, header);

        var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var characterSet = ((HttpWebResponse) response).CharacterSet;
        var responseEncoding = characterSet == ""
            ? Encoding.UTF8
            : Encoding.GetEncoding(characterSet ?? "utf-8");
        var responsestream = response.GetResponseStream();
        if (responsestream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(characterSet));
        }
        using (responsestream)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responsestream, responseEncoding);
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(@"result: " + result);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tested your method with 2 legged OAuth?

Comment: No, BL just uses an OAuth 1.0 like flow.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who is looking for way simpler solution. This works with WooCommerce and probably with other services. For WooCommerce token/tokenSecret is null.

```
var client = new RestClient($"{StoreHttp}/wp-json/wc/v3/products")
{
    Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, token, tokenSecret)
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Just for the benefit of other readers, the `RestClient` above is from the [RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/) library.

Comment: RestSharp does the job, thx for the hint @ramunas !

Comment: For anyone else doing one-legged OAuth 1, pass null for `token` and `tokenSecret` on line 3. You can change the signature method through parameter 5 if needed. `Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, null, null, OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha256)`.

Answer (score 1):

Example with: **RestSharp** version: 108.0.3

Do not need to write code for signature creation. RestSharp does it all for you.

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


var client = new RestClient(URL);
var oAuth1 = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(
                consumerKey: ConsumerKey,
                consumerSecret: ConsumerSecret,
                token: Token,
                tokenSecret: TokenSecret,
                OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha256);
oAuth1.Realm = Realm; // if Realm has otherwise ignore

client.Authenticator = oAuth1;

var request = new RestRequest(URL, Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject);
           
request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still getting forbidden error. but works in postman.. any suggestion please. I am struck..

Comment: @anand make sure you are using a valid OAuthSignatureMethod.

Comment: Thanks Raju. yes it worked. also voted up of answer. (y)