# How unescape RFC 3986 string

Tags: c#, rfc3986

I've a [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) encoded string in the form `%x##`. For example the space character is encoded as `%x20` instead of `%20`. How can I decode it in C#?
Using the decode method of `Uri`, `HttpUtility` or `WebUtility` classes the string **was not decoded**.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846487/how-to-get-uri-escapedatastring-to-comply-with-rfc-3986. its a possible duplicate

Comment: A space (ascii 20) was not allowed so it was replaced with the encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to `Replace` all `%x##` as well as `%##` matches:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string demo = "abc%x20def%20pqr";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
      demo, 
    "%x?([0-9A-F]{2})", 
      m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString(), 
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

  Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  abc def pqr
```

Comment: is there not any standard .NET method that do this?

Comment: @Matteo: it seems that we have to implement `%x##` case manually; `Uri.UnescapeDataString()` is ok for `%##` escapements

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:
You can try:

Reference: [How to get Uri.EscapeDataString to comply with RFC 3986](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846487/how-to-get-uri-escapedatastring-to-comply-with-rfc-3986)

```
    var escapedString = new StringBuilder(Uri.EscapeDataString(value));

    for (int i = 0; i < UriRfc3986CharsToEscape.Length; i++) {
        escapedString.Replace(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i], Uri.HexEscape(UriRfc3986CharsToEscape[i][0]));
    }

    // Return the fully-RFC3986-escaped string.
    return escaped.ToString();
```