# Can't upload an image using Ruby on rails, Paperclip, Heroku and AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have been doing the One Month Rails course. In the session "Paperclip to Amazon S3 Images on Heroku" i need to upload images using Paperclip on AWS on Heroku.

I have the option to upload a photo: http://arcane-shore-2097.herokuapp.com/pins/new

But after clicking "Create Pin" i got an error:

**We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.**

I have done all the steps, but something is not working correct

Here is my Github: https://github.com/frankzk/pinteresting

Heres is my Logs:

```
Gourmandises@GOURMANDISES-PC ~/desktop/pinteresting (master)
$ heroku logs
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:33.975266+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/index.html
.erb within layouts/application (13.5ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:33.978253+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 19ms (
Views: 13.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:33.958900+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#index as HTML
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:33.977595+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (1.3ms)
←[33m2014-05-28T04:22:34.369537+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/images/medium/missing.png host=arcane-shore-2097.herokuapp.com request_id=d91
1e565-fb96-4048-8e97-41a702823754 fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms s
ervice=87ms status=404 bytes=1829
←[33m2014-05-28T04:22:34.379829+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-3d6ac658b37f1391e8e7ad14c065d776.css host=arcane-shore-209
7.herokuapp.com request_id=d6701c20-cae5-4400-a1ec-e2e8c790c6b7 fwd="190.114.248
.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=93ms status=304 bytes=133
←[33m2014-05-28T04:22:34.381667+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/assets/application-958ecb4fb9542c4780a50a5263b53b34.js host=arcane-shore-2097
.herokuapp.com request_id=aeb3ab9b-e47b-46b2-8e54-222a88be4e89 fwd="190.114.248.
109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=97ms status=304 bytes=133
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.291226+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/images/mediu
m/missing.png" for 190.114.248.109 at 2014-05-28 04:22:34 +0000
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368555+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ru
by/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368561+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingE
rror (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368573+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'

←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368563+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in
`call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368566+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368576+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368577+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middlewa
re.rb:26:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368580+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368564+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `
call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368588+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ru
by/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368567+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368572+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368587+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ru
by/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368590+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368568+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in t
agged'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368571+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368578+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368570+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368575+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368585+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368582+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368592+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368583+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368581+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.368586+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
←[33m2014-05-28T04:22:34.720225+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/images/medium/missing.png host=arcane-shore-2097.herokuapp.com request_id=16c
f2245-1faa-4a7d-89c0-d9c47b1fbcc1 fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms s
ervice=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.714980+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/images/mediu
m/missing.png" for 190.114.248.109 at 2014-05-28 04:22:34 +0000
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719414+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719422+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m ActionController::RoutingE
rror (No route matches [GET] "/images/medium/missing.png"):
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719424+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in
`call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719427+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719426+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `
call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719429+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719431+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in t
agged'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719432+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719434+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719438+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'

←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719436+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719441+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719443+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middlewa
re.rb:26:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719439+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719446+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719444+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719455+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719451+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719448+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719457+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ru
by/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719460+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ru
by/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719461+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719450+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719453+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0
/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:34.719458+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ru
by/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:36.182227+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/pins/new" fo
r 190.114.248.109 at 2014-05-28 04:22:36 +0000
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:36.393015+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/_form.html
.erb (157.2ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:36.394461+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (0.5ms)
←[33m2014-05-28T04:22:36.438942+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/pins/new host=arcane-shore-2097.herokuapp.com request_id=b4a031c5-97b2-4bf5-a
866-c755cdf22cdd fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=256ms stat
us=304 bytes=887
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:36.191863+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#new as HTML
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:36.393265+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/new.html.e
rb within layouts/application (157.7ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:22:36.427215+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 235ms
(Views: 159.8ms | ActiveRecord: 25.6ms)
←[33m2014-05-28T04:23:03.148051+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET pat
h=/pins/new host=arcane-shore-2097.herokuapp.com request_id=70c795ca-a65e-4cd9-b
8f0-8cac0f9e4e2f fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=35ms statu
s=304 bytes=847
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:03.113981+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started GET "/pins/new" fo
r 190.114.248.109 at 2014-05-28 04:23:03 +0000
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:03.128540+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/_form.html
.erb (4.0ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:03.128672+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered pins/new.html.e
rb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:03.130235+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered layouts/_header
.html.erb (0.7ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:03.130641+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 13ms (
Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:03.116729+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#new as HTML
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.387929+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started POST "/pins" for 1
90.114.248.109 at 2014-05-28 04:23:07 +0000
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.621457+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.394488+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"??
?", "authenticity_token"=>"3V8VcfPu/TLZRTNSpXAkpr/Ljz7TozETCrj++6fNmBg=", "pin"=
>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f0b9c28a6c8 @tempfile=#<Tem
pfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140528-2-11b06h6>, @original_filename="4601_1346405869
_7587.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data
; name=\"pin[image]\"; filename=\"4601_1346405869_7587.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: im
age/jpeg\r\n">, "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Pin"}
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.404862+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-w
glxgj.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.394374+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by PinsControll
er#create as HTML
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.716143+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.822689+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:07.985010+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "3
00x300>" '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj20140528-2-oovse
s'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:08.592273+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj20140528-2-oovses'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:08.781793+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:08.662351+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-w
glxgj.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:08.974084+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:09.152338+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: identify -forma
t %m '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:09.288490+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: convert '/tmp/f
65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "1
00x100>" '/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj20140528-2-1tm6e
wc'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.087103+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Command :: file -b --mime
'/tmp/f65eb72886e01c194ea9e49bb95cf1ed20140528-2-wglxgj20140528-2-1tm6ewc'
←[33m2014-05-28T04:23:10.501345+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=POST pa
th=/pins host=arcane-shore-2097.herokuapp.com request_id=add40038-e52b-412b-bed9
-f171b8137c14 fwd="190.114.248.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4095ms status
=500 bytes=1754
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.468569+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [AWS S3 403 0.161086 0 ret
ries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"pinteresting_frankz",:content
_length=>94339,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter
: 4601_1346405869_7587.jpg,:key=>"pins/images/000/000/015/original/4601_13464058
69_7587.jpg") AWS::S3::Errors::SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we ca
lculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing m
ethod.
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.468587+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.294838+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m [paperclip] saving /pins/i
mages/000/000/015/original/4601_1346405869_7587.jpg
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.476544+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Ser
ver Error in 3082ms
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.481128+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.481134+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m AWS::S3::Errors::Signature
DoesNotMatch (The request signature we calculated does not match the signature y
ou provided. Check your key and signing method.):
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.481136+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/pins_con
troller.rb:22:in `create'
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.481137+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2014-05-28T04:23:10.481139+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I followed this steps, but i cant get with the error: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Comment: Can you post the actual error in your heroku logs? Just run `heroku logs` in your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the error:

> AWS::S3::Errors::Signature DoesNotMatch (The request signature we
>   calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key
>   and signing method.):

Looks like an error with your AWS access key. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777078/amazon-mws-request-signature-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-provided) recommends you may have leading or trailing slashes in your key definitions

Answer (score 0):

Your access key is in invalid format for amazon to read it properly.

Comment: If you'd like me to take a closer look in the next 30 min, click to my profile and connect with me on video chat.