# AWS S3 ajax PUT returning 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided'?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 via a pre-signed URL. I've verified that the URL indeed works by testing it with `curl`

```
curl --request PUT --upload file {filename} "{url}"
```

It pushes it up there A-OK.

However, when trying it from javascript, I get this message:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I've taken as many debugging steps as I can come up with -- for instance, making sure that the content-types and Content Lengths match between the pre-signed url and what I actually try to upload.

I found this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777078/amazon-mws-request-signature-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-provided) And tried everything in there:

- My Keys have no trailing spaces or slashes
- My bucketname doesn't have a slash in it.
- Tried URL encoding my key -- no difference
- Made sure my keyname is compliant

So, I'm at a bit of a loss. Could anyone identify what would be causing S3 to reject this request?

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('[type=submit]').click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                
                console.log($('#id_attachment').get(0).files[0].size);

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                    console.log(evt.target.result);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/simple.png?Signature=vYIEOmAay9v6zwB1cz78FhXv6Yo%3D&Expires=1416243285&AWSAccessKeyId=ACCESSKEY',
                        type: 'PUT',
                        contentType: "image/png",
                        data: evt.target.result,
                        success: function () {
                            console.log('Uploaded data successfully.');
                        }
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString($('#id_attachment').get(0).files[0]);

            });


        });
```

Comment: Another possible cause for this is when your computer local time has a noticeable offset from amazon's. Above one minute offset triggers this error for me.

Comment: The error message is different in that case.

Answer (score 2):

When creating the pre-signed URL, are you specifying a Content-Type of image/png, or any Content-Type at all?

If you aren't, because you are including a Content-Type in the browser upload, the signature mismatch Amazon might be referring to is that the ajax PUT *does* have a Content-Type header, but signature on the signed URL does not.

I recently ran into this issue because I'm creating pre-signed URLs with the .NET AWSSDK, and not specifying a content type at the time of the URL generation.

Uploads work fine from some run-of-the-mill sample C# code, but failed in my browser app because the framework I was using automatically appended the Content-Type header, causing the mismatch. Re-playing the request with a web debbugger (I'm using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)), and removing the Content-Type header from the browser's request worked, and is what led me to figuring out what was causing the mismatch for me.