# Signing S3 urls fails (The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to generate signed URLs to upload and download objects in my S3 bucket, but it fails with "SignatureDoesNotMatch" as per below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ66RWEJPYWX6PL2A</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>GET
```

I understand that this is a symptom for the problem described here

[Amazon MWS - request signature calculated does not match the signature provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777078/amazon-mws-request-signature-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-provided)

that is, my credentials is somehow wrong. I double checked my `.aws/credentials` file and generated new ones. Moreover, I can do other AWS operations with these credentials, such as querying dynamoDb or listing my buckets.

The code I use to generate the URLs, I copied from here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

```
final ZonedDateTime expiration = ZonedDateTime.now().plusSeconds(expirationSeconds);

final GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
    bucketName, objectId.toString());
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(isUpload ? HttpMethod.PUT : HttpMethod.GET);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(Date.from(expiration.toInstant()));

return amazonS3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toURI();
```

And, yes, my bucket exists. How can I get to the bottom with this?

Comment: The error message is cut in the middle. Could you post the whole thing?

Comment: Do something simpler to test if it's genuinely a credentials error, for example do a simple list of the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was using that chrome plugin "Advanced REST client" to send the request and I guess some CORS rule will make the request fail from that apps' JavaScript. Doing the request from the address filed of the browser works.