# Carrierwave and S3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with authentication, i try to upload but i get this

`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

initializer carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config| # optional, defaults to "fog"
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],                        # required
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY"],                        # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV["AWS_BUCKET_NAME"]                       # required
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

gem "carrierwave"
gem "fog"
gem "figaro"

set the environment variables

i also created a bucket in S3.

Is there anything i am missing here? It works locally though.

Also changed the image_uploader.rb to `storage :fog`

Comment: check that you have set the var AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY in the env.

Comment: the variable is set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777078/amazon-mws-request-signature-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-provided

Comment: validate spaces in secret key

Comment: there are no spaces...