# Upload File to AWS .Error When Using AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, cdn, aws-sdk

I have been trying to upload file to AWS S3 , below is the code that I am trying

```
private static void UploadToAWS(string localFilePath, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket, string fileNameInS3)
{
    string accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMAZON_S3_ACCESSKEY"].ToString();
    string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMAZON_S3_SECRETKEY"].ToString();

    AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
    {
        ServiceURL = "http://test.s3.amazonaws.com",

    };
    IAmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey,secretKey,asConfig);


    TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);

    TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

    if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
    {
        request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name
    }
    else
    {   // subdirectory and bucket name
        request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
    }
    request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3
    request.FilePath = localFilePath; //local file name
    request.Headers.CacheControl = "public";
    request.Headers.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(3);
    request.Headers.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
    utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer
}


  UploadToAWS(@"D:\core_gz.min.js", "test123", "test/build/", "core_gz.min.js");
```

When I execute this I get the following error

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your key and signing method.

Can any one help me here, what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon MWS - request signature calculated does not match the signature provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777078/amazon-mws-request-signature-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-provided)

Comment: @venky i checked this before posting the question here, but that didn't work out for me, how can this be an duplicate one

Comment: On which line the error is thrown if you are debugging.

Comment: @Venky  here  when its uploading the file to utility.Upload(request);

Comment: Change this  @"/" to  @"\" and then try

Comment: @SoftwareNerd may be it's worth posting here the content what you are building in the `request` object. It's  definitely has to do with some syntax.

Comment: @Venky you already have the complete code there

Comment: any how i fixed the  issue, when i passed the region in the config its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post the answer if in case it might help some one else who has the same issue

```
      private static void UploadToAWS(string localFilePath, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket, string fileNameInS3)
      {
         string accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMAZON_S3_ACCESSKEY"].ToString();
         string secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AMAZON_S3_SECRETKEY"].ToString();

         AmazonS3Config asConfig = new AmazonS3Config()
          {
    ServiceURL = "http://test.s3.amazonaws.com",
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1 // this line fixed the issue
          };
         IAmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey,secretKey,asConfig);


       TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);

       TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

      if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
       {
         request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name
       }
      else
      {   // subdirectory and bucket name
       request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
     }
      request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3
      request.FilePath = localFilePath; //local file name
      request.Headers.CacheControl = "public";
      request.Headers.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(3);
      request.Headers.ContentEncoding = "gzip";
      utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer
   }
```

Adding this line in the config fixed my issue

```
    RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1
```