# How to configure Logstash to parse AWS ELB logs?

Tags: docker, logstash, amazon-elb, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I want to parse AWS ELB logs [stored in a S3 bucket] from Logstash that is set up inside a dockerised ELK stack.

I cloned [this](https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker) repo. [Here](http://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/) are it's docs.

I added my logstash config file like this [and commented out all the others]:

`# AWS ELB configuration file
ADD ./aws_elb_logs.conf /etc/logstash/conf.d/aws_elb_logs.conf`

The config file is the following:

```
input {
    s3 {
        # Logging_user AWS creds
        access_key_id     => "fjnsdfjnsdjfnjsdn"
        secret_access_key => "asdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd"

        bucket            => "elb-access-logs"

        region            => "us-west-2"

        # keep track of the last processed file
        sincedb_path    => "./last-s3-file"
        codec           => "json"
        type            => "elb"
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] == "elb" {
        grok {
            match => [ 'message', '%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:loadbalancer} %{IP:client_ip}:%{NUMBER:client_port:int} (?:%{IP:backend_ip}:%{NUMBER:backend_port:int}|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:response_processing_time:float} (?:%{NUMBER:elb_status_code:int}|-) (?:%{NUMBER:backend_status_code:int}|-) %{NUMBER:received_bytes:int} %{NUMBER:sent_bytes:int} "(?:%{WORD:verb}|-) (?:%{GREEDYDATA:request}|-) (?:HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}|-( )?)" "%{DATA:userAgent}"( %{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher} %{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})?' ]
        }
        grok {
            match => [ "request", "%{URIPROTO:http_protocol}" ]
        }
        geoip {
            source  => "client_ip"
            target  => "geoip"
            add_tag => [ "geoip" ]
        }
        useragent {
            source => "userAgent"
        }
        date {
            match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
        }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => localhost
        port => "9200"
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
    stdout {
      debug => true
   }
}
```

When I create the container, I get the following error log from Logstash:

```
==> /var/log/logstash/logstash.log <==
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-18T13:04:40.798000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline aborted due to error", :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:88:in `config_init'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:72:in `config_init'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:79:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:74:in `register'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-18T13:04:43.801000+0000", :message=>"stopping pipeline", :id=>"main"}
```

I cannot understand what is/am going/doing wrong!

Any pointers would be welcome..

EDIT:

Now there is this:
 `==> /var/log/logstash/logstash.log <==
{:timestamp=>"2016-10-18T14:26:50.492000+0000", :message=>"A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.\n  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::S3 access_key_id=>\"gsfgdfgdfgdfgdfg\", secret_access_key=>\"dsfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdfg\", bucket=>\"elb-access-logs-dr\", region=>\"us-west-2\", sincedb_path=>\"./last-s3-file\", codec=><LogStash::Codecs::JSON charset=>\"UTF-8\">, type=>\"elb\", use_ssl=>true, delete=>false, interval=>60, temporary_directory=>\"/opt/logstash/logstash\">\n  Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.", :level=>:error}`

Comment: Is [your previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087769/how-to-send-aws-elb-logs-to-an-elk-stack-inside-docker) question still relevant or does this one replace it?

Comment: This replaces it as more specific.Thanks

Comment: Cool, would you mind deleting the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of the container with logstash version > 2, your configuration for the elasticsearch output plugin is where the error is coming from. With logstash version 2, the configuration option `port` was removed, the port being configured with the host in the `hosts` option ([cf doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-hosts)).

Comment: Thank you , that made some progress! Now , I have another one :\. Please check the edit above

Comment: @KostasDemiris I've taken a look to the edit. I have zero experience with s3 buckets and the s3 plugin, so I can only say what's in the log you provided, that there is a problem with your credentials. If you want help on this problem, you'll have to ask another question

Comment: It,s OK. I have found it. For reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/20720402/1163667 .
Thank you again. it was such a sneaky one ;]

Comment: @KostasDemiris Congrats! I sure would not have been able to help on that problem