# Signature issues when creating signed URL for S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am running into issues when generating a signed URL for a **public** S3 bucket. I get the issue when doing a PUT request:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

A bit of information - I am using:

- `node` version 5.8
- `aws-sdk`version 2.7.10

I use the `aws-sdk` like this:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: 'eu-west-1'
})
const s3 = new AWS.S3()
```

I generate the URL this way:

```
const params = {
  Key: FILE_KEY,
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  ContentType: image/jpeg,
  Expires: 60,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  Metadata: {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31556926'
  }
}

const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)
```

The generated URL looks like this:

```
https://companyxyz.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/
image/5843df4a15c6fccf4501cab9.jpg?
AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxx&
Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&
Expires=1480843142&
Signature=YvUEGntDLVUUuyVuDMxF5yXXBnI%3D
&x-amz-acl=public-read&
x-amz-meta-cache-control=max-age%3D31556926
```

Comment: check your access keys, as seen here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8002444/2383685 . Your code looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have looked into it in great detail, but it does not seem to resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to sig v2 and sig v4

From the documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html
and here
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

notice that in sig v4,

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/examplebucket/test.txt
?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Credential=<your-access-key-id>/20130721/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
```

your access-key-id is part of X-Amz-Credential

while for sig v2

```
https://elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com?
&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
```

AWSAccessKeyId has its own paramater.

Your example shows that you are using sig v2

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html
also mentions that some regions do not support sig v2

EU (Frankfurt) Region
EU (London) Region

EU (Frankfurt) is eu-central-1
which is strange, because it sig v2 should not work in eu-central-1.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing `region`. I created a new bucket in `eu-central-1` and everything worked. No matter what, I was not able to generate a working signed URL for `eu-west-1`.

Would love to hear any insights.