# How to upload files to AWS-S3 with Angular $http PUT

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angularjs-http

In my Angular application I try to upload a file to AWS-S3 with `$http.put(url, file)`.

However it's not working, I get back a HTTP-403 Forbidden telling me that the signature s3 calculated differs from the one I provided BUT if I make the same request with curl like `curl -X PUT -T file url` then everything is ok the file gets uploaded. So either the way $http.put is working is bad (for this task) or curl has some magic. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777078 ?

Comment: I checked it now, but none of the answers applies to my case. With curl I can make it work but not with $http :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading a file with the $http service, it is important to set `Content-Type: undefined`.

```
  var config = { headers: {
                   "Content-Type": undefined,
                  }
               };

  var promise = $http.put(url, file, config);
```

The default content type for the $http service is `application/json`. By setting `Content-Type: undefined`, the $http service omits the `Content-Type` header and the XHR API sets the `Content-Type` header to that of the file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

I couldn't find out why `$http` is not working .. even I found strange things according to this topic.

So first I "fetched" the file from html like this:

```
<input flex="40" type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().$parent.selectAttachment(this)">
```

becuase I didn't want to create a directive for this testing purpose. The `selectAttachment` function simply set the file as a property for my controller.

Then seemingly it was ok, I could read e.g `this.attachment.name` or `this.attachment.size`, but when I wrote `$http.put(url, this.attachment)` I got the signature-mismatch error.

Then I tried the same with XHR as in this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

Never lucky...

Then, as a last resort, I tried to fetch the file by not setting it via angular but `const file = document.getElementById('report-attachment').files[0];`
and finally it worked for me. Intrestingly, fetching the file with `getElementById` AND using $http still not work, neither 1 or 2 3rd party angular uploader I tried, only with XHR o.o

The final "solution" which works for me:

HTML:

```
<input flex="40" id="report-attachment" type="file">
```

JS:

```
            const file = document.getElementById('report-attachment').files[0];
            const url = r && r.data;
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('PUT', url);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.debug('success');
                    } else {
                        console.error('error');
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr.send(file);
```