# Remote server (403) Forbidden error while using WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to query some URL using `WebClient`.

I have a collection which I loop through to get the `QueryString` value, and build final URL, and then pass it on to client.

The very first time it gets executed well, I get proper response, however, when it goes in loop second time, I get the error:

> System.Net.WebException --> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

If I get response for very first time. Then I should get for rest of the collection too.

Any clue why? What I might be missing?

Below is the code snippet I am using.

```
 using(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\sample.text")) {
    foreach(var f in fileCollections) {
        strFinalURL = string.Empty;

        strFinalURL = "someURL" + f; // f can be considered as querystring param value

        try {
            using(var client = new WebClient()) {

                test = client.DownloadString(strFinalURL);
                if (!test.Contains("somecondition")) {
                    file.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        } catch (System.Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all URLs from the same domain? The URL that returns 403, is it accessible via a browser?

Comment: @codingstill yes, all URLs are from same domain and accessible via brower

Comment: If everything you said is correct, then I suspect server throttling is playing a part. What happens if you slow things down a bit with a strategically placed `Thread.Sleep`?

Comment: Download [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) and send an HTTP request using fiddler and look at the data being received and sent.

Comment: @spender, Yup Throttling is playing role here.. when I am slowing down the process.. it works... Thanks

Comment: @Amit: I stated this as an answer for you to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything you said is correct, then I suspect server throttling is playing a part. Try adding a `Thread.Sleep` in your loop to slow things down.

Answer (score 17):

Some web servers can block requests based on the user agent string they provide. In your case, you send an empty string as a user agent. Try to add the user agent of a browser, any browser would be fine.

For example:

```
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
```

For a list of user agents, you can click [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

Comment: This fixed it for me, would never have thought of that!