# link check gets status bad result

Tags: c#, httpclient, link-checking

We have some resources which contains links to external sites. However, we want to avoid dead links and have implemented a ping routine written in c# .net6.

We loop through all links and do a HEAD and a GET request with HttpClient. Most sites return OK200 but some return bad request, forbidden and so forth. But if we inspect the link in the browser, the site/link works as expected.

If we get a 404 we mark the link as dead and someone should do something manually and update the link. We have added a useragent to httpclient.

How can we avoid the bad requests returned to the httpclient?

Comment: It is possible that they detect the user-agent and can detect that this request doesn't come from a browser. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715970/remote-server-403-forbidden-error-while-using-webclient where there was a similar issue

Comment: we have added a useragent but it was a custom string. I will give it a go and try a more browser specific useragent