# Download Web Page using C# giving 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to download a webpage in C# but it is giving 403 Forbidden Error.

URL: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1012968/000175272422189567/0001752724-22-189567.txt

Code:

```
using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{                       
    try
    {                           
        wc.DownloadFile(webURL, filePath);                                                                                                                                                                                
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        // check exception object for the error
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905471/3390788

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebClient 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272067/webclient-403-forbidden)

Comment: Added User-Agent Other but still no luck.

Comment: Please edit the post with the new code 

Comment: Also, there are *several* answers to that question.  You may want to run through them to see if any one of them is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Tried all the other options given in the post. Getting 403 Forbidden Error. wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");

Comment: Please edit the post with the code you've attempted 

Comment: Your Request Originates from an Undeclared Automated Tool

To allow for equitable access to all users, SEC reserves the right to limit requests originating from undeclared automated tools. Your request has been identified as part of a network of automated tools outside of the acceptable policy and will be managed until action is taken to declare your traffic.

Please declare your traffic by updating your user agent to include company specific information.

Comment: This is resolved by adding company specific info on User Agent. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.sec.gov/os/webmaster-faq#code-support

Answer (score 0):

Add company specific info on User Agent.