# C# decodes URL containing %2F on path, is there any way to instruct API to send the URL as it is?

Tags: c#, urlencode

I am having a URL in below format
abcd.com/xyz/pqr%2Fss/abc

I want this to be send to server as it is.
When I build Uri using System.Uri it converts it to abcd.com/xyz/pqr/ss/abc
and it fails as I don't have a URL with the specified path.

When I tried with double encoding 
(abcd.com/xyz/pqr%252Fss/abc) it send the Uri as it is but it fails as server side it is converted to (abcd.com/xyz/pqr%2Fss/abc)

Comment: If it sends the URL "as is" as per your second example, it fails on the server.  So yes, there is a way to do that -- the double-encoding method.

Comment: Then you have an issue with the server.  What's the server-side?

Comment: And you have tried using this HTMLEncode on the string before sending it over? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: Here is answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/c-net-getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash

Comment: Here is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/c-net-getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash

Answer (score 0):

If you construct your uri as such:

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://abcd.com/xyz/pqr%2Fss/abc")
```

Access the encoded string like this:

```
u.OriginalString
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but I found the solution: when you use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to be sure that the application will read the url right you have to construct the link this way:

```
http://www.abcd.com/xyz?val=pqr%2Fss
```

and not like this

```
http://www.abcd.com/xyz/pqr%2Fss
```

where `pqr%2Fss` is the result of the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("SOME STRING")`