# How to make System.Uri not to unescape %2f (slash) in path?

Tags: .net

System.Uri constructor insists on unescaping %2f sequences as foward slashes, when it sees them in path portion of URL. How could I avoid that behaiviour?

I've seen [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94109/system-uri-constructor-evaluates-escaped-slashes-and-removes-double-slashes) ticket on this thig, but workaround is not working for .net 4 as far is I understand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18511985/420849 - this is solution for similar problem in PowerShell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It keeps the original string internally, for example, the following code:

```
    Uri u = new Uri("http://www.example.com/path?var=value%2fvalue");
    Console.WriteLine(u.OriginalString);
```

will display

```
http://www.example.com/path?var=value%2fvalue
```

**EDIT**: I have update the code found in the [Connect Link Workaround](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94109/system-uri-constructor-evaluates-escaped-slashes-and-removes-double-slashes) for recent .NET versions. Here it is:

```
// System.UriSyntaxFlags is internal, so let's duplicate the flag privately
private const int UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes = 0x2000000;
private const int SimpleUserSyntax = 0x20000;

public static void LeaveDotsAndSlashesEscaped(Uri uri)
{
    if (uri == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = uri.GetType().GetField("m_Syntax", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fieldInfo == null)
        throw new MissingFieldException("'m_Syntax' field not found");

    object uriParser = fieldInfo.GetValue(uri);
    fieldInfo = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fieldInfo == null)
        throw new MissingFieldException("'m_Flags' field not found");

    object uriSyntaxFlags = fieldInfo.GetValue(uriParser);

    // Clear the flag that we don't want
    uriSyntaxFlags = (int)uriSyntaxFlags & ~UnEscapeDotsAndSlashes;
    uriSyntaxFlags = (int)uriSyntaxFlags & ~SimpleUserSyntax;
    fieldInfo.SetValue(uriParser, uriSyntaxFlags);
}
```

Of course, it's a hack, so you should use it at your own risks :-)

Comment: Yes, but `new Uri("http://www.example.com/value%2fvalue").ToString()` produces `"http://www.example.com/value/value"`. I should edit question though - thanks for the tip.

Comment: Totally offtopic, but thanks for your work on HAP. Have been using it for ages.

Comment: @Artem - thanks :-). for the Uri, I think it's 100% by design, per RFC 3986. But note value%2fvalue in the PATH part or in the QUERY part is not handled the same. You can also use uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.SerializationInfoString, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped) to have "almost" the original string (except for the PATH part).

Comment: Sad part is that HttpWebRequest uses System.Uri and one of our systems with plain JSON over HTTP interface requires %2f sequence in PATH part of the query URL. Well, I think it means sockets.

Comment: @Artem - I have updated my answer with an adaptation of the "connect" workaround

Answer (score 4):

As I have posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307833/creating-an-uri-in-net-automatically-urldecodes-all-parameters-from-passed-stri/10890899#10890899), you can disable this behaviour via a configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [2011 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776225) above by Simon Mourier no longer works on recent versions of .NET. This is because it uses reflection to look up a field inside the `UriParser` class, and update its value. This field is no longer named `m_Flags`, but just `_flags` now. It's not particularly surprising that this field name would have changed in the past 12 years across many versions of .NET.

Here is an alternative that works for .NET 7 (I haven't tried any other versions). Call this function at the start of your program, and adjust the list of schemes to fit your use case:

```cs
public static void DoNotSimplifyUris()
{
    const int CanonicalizeAsFilePath = 0x01000000;
    const int ConvertPathSlashes = 0x00400000;
    const int CompressPath = 0x00800000;
    
    var getSyntaxMethod = typeof (UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (getSyntaxMethod == null)
    {
        throw new MissingMethodException("UriParser", "GetSyntax");
    }

    foreach (var scheme in new[] { "http", "https" })
    {
        // call with "http" and "https" to update both UriParser objects (see UriParser class for all instances)
        var uriParser = getSyntaxMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { scheme });
        if (uriParser == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"Unexpected: UriParser.getSyntax({scheme}) returned null");
        }

        // get reference to UriParser._flags field
        var flagsFieldInfo = typeof(UriParser).GetField("_flags",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (flagsFieldInfo == null)
        {
            throw new MissingFieldException("UriParser", "_flags");
        }

        // get value of that field on the UriParser object we're looking at (either the http or https instance)
        var flagsValue = flagsFieldInfo.GetValue(uriParser);
        if (flagsValue == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Could not extract the value of UriParser._flags for the {scheme} instance");
        }

        // convert to the underlying int representation to unset some flags
        var flags = (int) flagsValue;
        flags &= ~CanonicalizeAsFilePath;
        flags &= ~ConvertPathSlashes;
        flags &= ~CompressPath;

        // save the modified value on the UriParser instance
        flagsFieldInfo.SetValue(uriParser, flags);
    }
}
```

This should also work with other changes made by `UriParser` to URIs. For example, by default it simplifies `/./` to simply `/` as if all URIs represented a file path.

I tried sending a request to `/foo/./bar` *without* calling this method, and the server received a `GET /foo/bar`. When calling it first, it receives `GET /foo/./bar`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to `URI.EscapeUriString` before construct new URI. It makes `%2F` looking like `%252F` and it's work just fine in my case.