# Creating an Uri in .NET automatically urldecodes all parameters from passed string

Tags: c#, .net, url, escaping

Suppose I want to create an Uri object from the following string:

```
string url = @"http://someserver.com?param1=1&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.otherserver.com";
Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
```

Expected result would be:

```
http://someserver.com?param1=1&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.otherserver.com
```

Obtained:

```
http://someserver.com/?param1=1&url=http://www.otherserver.com
```

The same behavior is noticed in many related methods that allow Uri creation: Uri.TryCreate, UriBuilder.Uri, etc.

How would I get an Uri that preserve initial encoded parameter?

Comment: Expected result of doing what? If I try your code in a Console Application `Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);` returns the encoded url

Comment: For other searching regarding this. It is actually the ToString() method that decodes the string. .OriginalString or .AbsoluteUri will return the encoded string. For a relative url, use .PathAndQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> As part of canonicalization in the constructor for some schemes,
>   escaped representations are compacted. The schemes for which URI will
>   compact escaped sequences include the following: file, http, https,
>   net.pipe, and net.tcp. For all other schemes, escaped sequences are
>   not compacted. For example: if you percent encode the two dots ".." as
>   "%2E%2E" then the URI constructor will compact this sequence for some
>   schemes. For example, the following code sample shows a URI
>   constructor for the http scheme.

So one workaround might be temporarily using a custom scheme (e.g. `leavemealone://`) to construct the URL objects (possibly through `UriBuilder`?).

Comment: Interestingly, I discovered the compaction to also occur with `rtsp://`. The documentation is vague about which are included (saying "some" schemes are left uncompacted, and ones which are compacted "include" these).

Answer (score 7):

In .NET4 you can disable Uri compaction for certain scheme [via a configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656542.aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
      <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Note that there are security implications related to disabling of the default behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

How did you "obtain" the URL? If I hover my mouse over it in Visual Studio, it indeed shows the decoded URL.

But whenever I access it through the `AbsoluteUri` property, it shows the encoded URL.

Comment: Well I'm describing observed behaviour. It's an asp.net mvc app but it does not matter.

Comment: I didn't ask what, I asked how.

Comment: ooops sorry. I formed using asp.net mvc routing but I need to make some tweeks to it.

Comment: I was responding to your "obtained". It only prints like that when you cast it to a string. The `AbsoluteUri` property gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by returning ToString() method of  UriBuilder class instead of using Uri property of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the library Flurl. It allows a fluent and correct build and analysis of URIs. See their examples. https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-url/

It is available as NuGet package. You don't need the HTTP-Stuff

```
    using Flurl;

    var url = "http://www.some-api.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("endpoint")
    .SetQueryParams(new {
        api_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeApiKey"],
        max_results = 20,
        q = "Don't worry, I'll get encoded!"
    })
    .SetFragment("after-hash");
```