# Is there a way to send escaped period character in Uri for HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to make a GET http request with period in url

ex **http://testsite.com/TestEndpoint/Members/first%2Elast%40testemail%2Ecom**

in above example first.last@testemail.com is escaped to **first%2Elast%40testemail%2Ecom**

The problem is HttpClient creates a Uri from the string which unescapes the **%2E** to **.** (part of the url turns to **first.last%40testmail.com**) which causes public API to throw endpoint not found error.

I can make this request from Postman and it works just fine but from .net HttpClient or WebRequest.Create fails.

Is there a way to tell HttpClient not to un-escape the url?

```
var uri = new Uri("http://testsite.com/TestEndpoint/Members/first%2Elast%40testemail%2Ecom");
```

I also tried [Creating an Uri in .NET automatically urldecodes all parameters from passed string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307833/creating-an-uri-in-net-automatically-urldecodes-all-parameters-from-passed-stri?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but that has no effect, not sure if that feature is broken or no longer supported.

Comment: Could you edit and append your code to make your issue more reproduceable?

Comment: Where does the initial escape happen?

Comment: @LGSon I am doing that `.Replace(".", "%2E")`

Comment: Well, since the `new Uri` _un-escape_ your result, simply don't do that replacement in the first place, and it should work as is, or no?

Comment: @LGSon I do need it escaped, Uri class un-escapes period characters.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but what if you pass in a string that has period character? ... Doesn't  it _escape_ those?

Comment: @LGSon Nope, Uri class unescapes periods and slashes. It only escapes unsafe Uri characters.

Comment: @JessedeWit It internally creates a Uri and calls Uri overload.

Comment: I believe this is a great question, and it feels like your case should be possible somehow...

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I'm given a signed url (including %2E) from a third party and then I'm unable to get the resource because HttpClient un-escapes the url so my request no longer matches the signed one. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to further "escape" your intended URL with:

```cs
client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://testsite.com/testendpoint?members=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("first%2Elast%40testemail%2Ecom"));
```

Comment: That will not work as that will cause string to turn into **http://testsite.com/testendpoint/first%252Elast%2540testemail%252Ecom**

Comment: You should not pass as an argument the escaped string into UrlEncode, but the actual unescaped string.

Comment: @MZanetti Passing that to the Uri constructor would produce the same problem, because it produces the same string.