# Accessing private members from powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get Uri to stop encoding '/'
As explained here:
[GETting a URL with an url-encoded slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash)

But how to achieve the same in powershell ?

I'm trying to follow the route of accessing private property and changing it's value but I can't get it to work.

`[Uri].GetProperties([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic)` - returns nothing

Any ideas?

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as the solution.

Answer (score 7):

This is working solution for PowerShell:

```
$uri = [Uri]"http://example.com/%2F"
# access the .PathAndQuery field to initialize the Uri object
$pathAndQuery = $uri.PathAndQuery
$flagsField = $uri.GetType().GetField("m_Flags", [Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance)
$flagsValue = [UInt64]$flagsField.GetValue($uri)
# remove flags Flags.PathNotCanonical and Flags.QueryNotCanonical
$flagsValue = [UInt64]($flagsValue -band (-bnot 0x30));
$flagsField.SetValue($uri, $flagsValue)
Write-Host $uri.AbsoluteUri
```

Thanks to google-api-dotnet-client [path](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/attachmentText?id=273&aid=2730000000&name=UriFactory.Modify%20patch&token=EJWVESGIeGM5_FrgW9E2a3r6gE0:1361351962225) :-) please note, that there is some difference with .net 2.0, my code is working for > .net 2.0 (for <= 2.0 versions, the type of `flagsValue` object will be `[Int32]` instead of `[Uint64]`)

Answer (score 1):

try this (like in your link):

```
$uri.GetType().GetField("m_Flags", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance -bor `
 [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic)
```

to get non public properties:

```
$uri.GetType().GetProperties( [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance -bor `
[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic )
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking that other post as what you need, you want this:

```
$uri = [uri]"http://example.com/%2F"
$f = [uri].getfield("m_Flags", "nonpublic,instance")
$v = [int]($f.getvalue($uri))
$f.setvalue($uri, [uint64]($v -band (-bnot 0x30)))
```

PowerShell's `-bnot` and `-band` bitwise operators don't work with any types bigger than `[int]` so I'm downcasting to `[int]` which does not overflow for the above case (which means flag values beyond `[int]::maxvalue` are not present.)

Comment: The code works fine but it has no effect on Uri unfortunately.

I'm getting http://0.0.0.0/myoriginalip/restofthepath (still parsed by Uri so '%2F' is still reversed to original '/'

I ran the same code in .net unit test and it works fine. I don't really understand why Powershell doesn't follow the same pattern. If anyone has better luck do let me know.

Comment: It is important to access PathAndQuery before doing the internal manipulation of the state. You are skipping that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri.GetType().GetProperties('Instance,NonPublic')
```