# HttpClient will Encode the url internally

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-6.0

Here is my link:

> 58.87.64.22/?{{%25}}cake\=1

When I open it in Chrome, it will give me 400 status code which is correct.

But When I open it using HTTP client, it will return 200 status code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var w = await client.GetAsync("http://58.87.64.22/?{{%25}}cake\\=1");
```

it seems HTTP client will encode the URL into this:

> 58.87.64.22/?%7B%7B%25%7D%7Dcake%5C=1

when I test the encoded URL in Chrome, it will open a webpage and will return 200 status code.

How to solve such a thing? I need to get 400 status code when sending request to this URL.

Comment: You need to send an invalid request? What's your use case, automated testing?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel yes I'm creating some automated testing.

Comment: This is because HttpClient uses Uri, you can try it for yourself by creating a new Uri

Comment: @T.Dominik please guide me on how to create a URI that skips encoding.

Comment: You can try something like this, but it's obsolete: new Uri(new Uri("http://58.87.64.22/"), "?{{%25}}cake\\=1", true); ....and then pass Uri to GetAsync instead of string.

Comment: @T.Dominik the code you gave will give `Invalid URI` error

Comment: @InsideMan you could use `Uri.TryCreate` before the `GetAsync`

Comment: @Julian `TryCreate` is for validating, I need to skip encoding.

Comment: @InsideMan you could disable the percent-encoding with the [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/schemesettings-element-uri-settings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#example)

Comment: @Julian thank you man, but I'm using the Uri inside the `HttpClient`

Comment: @InsideMan yes but you could generate the Uri with the config (which won't use percent-encoding) and provide it in `GetAsync` ... it won't encode the uri again, would it?

Comment: @Julian how to use such an XML configuration in a dll library project?

Comment: This works: `new Uri(new Uri("http://58.87.64.22/"), "?{{%25}}cake\\=1", true);` and gives 400 status. @T.Dominik just didn't specify the "http://" part of Uri, hence the Invalid URI exception

Comment: @LegkovIvan stackoverflow automatically converts it to the actual link...eh

Comment: @T.Dominik is there another way which is not obsolete?

Comment: @InsideMan you may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76942781/16871250) answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass a `Uri` object instantiated via the overload having a [`UriCreationOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uricreationoptions.dangerousdisablepathandquerycanonicalization?#system-uricreationoptions-dangerousdisablepathandquerycanonicalization) argument with `DangerousDisablePathAndQueryCanonicalization` set to `true`.

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the path and query are validated and normalized.
> `true` to disable path and query validation; `false` to enable it.

```
var options = new UriCreationOptions 
{
    DangerousDisablePathAndQueryCanonicalization = true
};
var uri = new Uri(@"http://58.87.64.22/?{{%25}}cake\=1", options);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

---

Fiddler shows that below request is being made without any encoding.

```
GET http://58.87.64.22/?{{%25}}cake\=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 58.87.64.22
```

Resulting in a Bad Request HTTP status code.

```
HTTP/1.1 400
```