# How do I stop System.Uri from unencoding a URL?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I stop the System.Uri class from unencoding an encoded URL passed into its constructor? Consider the following code:-

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://foo.bar/foo%2FBar");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
uri = new Uri("http://foo.bar/foo%2FBar", false);
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
uri = new Uri("http://foo.bar/foo%2FBar", true);
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

In each case the output is "http://foo.bar/foo/bar". How can I ensure that after instantiating a Uri instance, Uri.AbsoluteUri will return "http://foo.bar/foo%2FBar"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Uri` class isn't used to generate an escaped URI, although you can use `uri.OriginalString` to retrieve the string used for initialization.  You should probably be using UrlEncode if you need to reencode a URI safely.

Also, as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zh9wcb3.aspx the `dontEscape` parameter in the Uri initializer has been deprecated and will always be false.

UPDATE:

Seems someone found a way (hack) to do this - [GETting a URL with an url-encoded slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/c-net-getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash)

Comment: I am already using UrlEncode. My problem is actually when attempting to construct a HttpWebRequest instance to make a REST call where the URL may have escaped characters in it (including a slash as demonstrated above). I was using the WebRequest.Create(UrlString) overload to create the request, and found that the URL being passed to the server was unencoding the encoded slash, causing a server-side error. Further testing revealed this was probably a problem with the Uri class, hence my question.

Comment: Thanks for the link there, PinnyM. Due to the "Terrible hack" nature of it, I'm wondering whether I should go that route, or take another tack entirely to solve my problem. Currently I'm attempting to call a REST service, but I have the flexibility to change this to a SOAP one instead, which should also alleviate this issue. Nevertheless, you've solved this particular problem, so I'm going to mark this as the correct answer.