# C# WebRequest.getResponse(): 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, webrequest, bad-request

I am trying to download a file from a server using System.Web.
It actually works, but some links give me trouble. The links look like this:

```
http://cdn.somesite.com/r1KH3Z%2FaMY6kLQ9Y4nVxYtlfrcewvKO9HLTCUBjU8IBAYnA3vzE1LGrkqMrR9Nh3jTMVFZzC7mxMBeNK5uY3nx5K0MjUaegM3crVpFNGk6a6TW6NJ3hnlvFuaugE65SQ4yM5754BM%2BLagqYvwvLAhG3DKU9SGUI54UAq3dwMDU%2BMl9lUO18hJF3OtzKiQfrC/the_file.ext
```

The code looks basically like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
WebResponse response = request.getResponse();
```

getResponse() always throws an exception (Error 400 Bad Request).
However, I know the link works because I can download the file with Firefox without problems.

I also tried to decode the link with Uri.UnescapeDataString(link), but that link wont even work in Firefox.

Other links work perfectly fine this way.. just these won't work.

### Edit:

Okay, i found something out using wireshark:

If i open the link using Firefox, this is sent:

```
&ME3@"dM*PNyAo PA:]GET /r1KH3Z%2FaMY6kLQ9Y4nVxYp5DyNc49t5kJBybvjbcsJJZ0IUJBtBWCgri3zfTERQught6S8ws1a%2BCo0RS5w3KTmbL7i5yytRpn2QELEPUXZTGYWbAg5eyGO2yIIbmGOcFP41WdrFRFcfk4hAIyZ7rs4QgbudzcrJivrAaOTYkEnozqmdoSCCY8yb1i22YtEAV/epd_outpost_12adb.flv HTTP/1.1
Host: cdn.somesite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I think only the first line is the problem, because WebRequest.Create(link) decodes the url:

```
&MEz.@!dM/nP9@~P>.GET /r1KH3Z/aMY6kLQ9Y4nVxYp5DyNc49t5kJBybvjbcsJJZ0IUJBtBWCgri3zfTERQught6S8ws1a%2BCo0RS5w3KTmbL7i5yytRpn2QELEPUXZTGYWbAg5eyGO2yIIbmGOcFP41WdrFRFcfk4hAIyZ7rs6Mmh1EsQQ4vJVYUwtbLBDNx9AwCHlWDfzfSWIHzaaIo/epd_outpost_12adb.flv HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Host: cdn.somesite.com
```

( %2F is replaced with / )

### Another edit:

I found out that the Uri class decodes the url automatically:
    Uri uri = new Uri(link); //link is not decoded
    Debug.WriteLine(uri.ToString()); //link is decoded here.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hard to tell, if you don't give the real url. Try to look at the communication that a browser does to get the response (with Live HTTP headers addon, or a tool like Wireshark) - that should give you a hint what to change in your request.

Comment: Uri class does that, it had a constructor with parameter dontEscape but it's obsolete and does nothing

Comment: Thanks, I just found this out. Is there any way to prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default, the `Uri` class will not allow an escaped `/` character (`%2f`) in a URI (even though this appears to be legal in my reading of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/embed%2fded");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri); // prints: http://example.com/embed/ded
```

(Note: [don't use Uri.ToString](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/uritostring_must_die.html) to print URIs.)

According to the [bug report for this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511010/erroneous-uri-parsing-for-encoded-reserved-characters-according-to-rfc-3986) on Microsoft Connect, this behaviour is by design, but you can work around it by adding the following to your app.config or web.config file:

```
<uri>
  <schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
  </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

(Since `WebRequest.Create(string)` just delegates to `WebRequest.Create(Uri)`, you would need to use this workaround no matter which method you call.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem.

And thanks for the Uri.ToString() hint.

Answer (score 3):

This has now changed in .NET 4.5. By default you can now use escaped slashes. I posted more info on this (including screenshots) in the comments here: [GETting a URL with an url-encoded slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash)