# Can I stop Uri from unencoding a url in WebRequest.Create?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri

The code itself isn't complex, it's just not working properly:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.co.uk%2F");
WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

I get a "Bad Request" back from the server, and after much MUCH digging, discovered that the Uri is being turned into

> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/sites/http%3A//www.mydomain.co.uk/

which is not what I asked for, and so it's having a whinge

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: it shouldn't be unencoding the url, it should leave it as it is (https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)

Comment: What happends if you just pass the string value into the `Create(` method?

`WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.co.uk%2F");`

Comment: It does the same - under the bonnet it just turns it straight in to a Uri

Comment: yeah, it's definitely the Uri that's doing.  Alas adding true doesn't make any difference (it's also deprecated I think)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# WebRequest.getResponse(): 400 Bad Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413795/c-sharp-webrequest-getresponse-400-bad-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415482/159341

According to [the bug report for this issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511010/erroneous-uri-parsing-for-encoded-reserved-characters-according-to-rfc-3986) on Microsoft Connect, this behaviour is by design, but you can work around it by adding the following to your app.config or web.config file:

```
<uri>
  <schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
  </schemeSettings>
</uri>
```

(Since WebRequest.Create(string) just delegates to WebRequest.Create(Uri), you would need to use this workaround no matter which method you call.)

Comment: Thank you! And good find.  Alas this didn't fix my webmaster tools problem, although I thought it would (for anyone else looking for the same solution as me!).  I shall soldier on though!