# Preserve an escaped Uri with HttpClient

Tags: c#, escaping, uri, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to use HttpClient to create a GET request with the following Uri:

http://test.com?action=enterorder&ordersource=acme&resid=urn%3Auuid%3A0c5eea50-9116-414e-8628-14b89849808d
As you can see, the resid param is escaped with %3A, ie the ":" character.

When I use this Uri in the HttpClient request, the url becomes:

http://test.com?action=enterorder&ordersource=acme&resid=urn:uuid:0c5eea50-9116-414e-8628-14b89849808d and I receive an error from the server because %3A is expected.

Anyone have any clue on what to do to preserve the escaped Uri when sending the request? It seems HttpClient always unescaped characters on the string before sending it.
Here is the code used:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://test.com?action=enterorder&ordersource=acme&resid=urn%3Auuid%3A0c5eea50-9116-414e-8628-14b89849808d");
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
   var resp = client.GetAsync(uri);
   if (resp.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        var responseContent = resp.Result.Content;
        string content = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  There's no reason why a server should process "%3A" in a url and not ":"

Comment: It's Adobe Content Server installed on an Apache server. I know it's a strange issue, but the call is expected to receive a %3A and not :

Comment: Does it still happen if you use the string overload of `GetAsync`? `client.GetAsync(uri.OriginalString);`

Comment: @keyboardP still not working :( Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Where are you using `uri`?  You create it, but it never gets used.  Have you tried `client.GetAsync("http://test.com?action=enterorder&ordersource=acme&resid=urn%3Auuid%3A0c5eea50-9116-414e-8628-14b89849808d"`?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I edited the question to add the uri var. Unfortunately, I tried to directly paste the uri string like you proposed but the url still got deencoded.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the server because ":" and "%3A" should be processed identically.

Comment: It has been a few years but we ran into this issue today. Do you have any ideas about how it could be fixed today? We are using .NET Core 2.0.

Comment: This issue is solved in .NET Core 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to test in .NET 4.5 as a bunch of improvements were made to Uri parsing for escaped chars.

You can also check out this SO question: [GETting a URL with an url-encoded slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash) which has a hack posted that you can use to force the URI to not get touched.

Comment: The setting in the web.config file proposed in one of the answers to that question is what worked for me, fortunately no need for hacks.

`<uri> 
<schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" />
</schemeSettings>
</uri>`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could try to encode this url part again to circumvent the issue. %3A would become %253A