# .net HttpWebRequest URL encoding in url parameters

Tags: .net

Does the HttpWebRequest class automatically encode URL parameter?
I have created a HttpWebRequest with URL "http://test.com/124?param=%2Ea".
When I capture a fiddler trace, I see the HTTP get request becomes "http://test.com/124?param=.a" i.e. "%2E" becomes ".".

I have tried setting up debugger in my code and I am sure the url I passed in HttpWebRequest is "http://test.com/124?param=%2Ea"
Do you know if HttpWebRequest does that automatically? And how can I disable it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce that, if I make request with %2E I see that in fiddler and if I just use "." I also see that. Anyway "." is allowed in url so if your backend decodes the url-parameter it should not matter if you use "." or %2E. What is your problem in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, although `%2e` is the url encoded equivalent of `.`,  you want the request url to remain the exact same way you typed it, right?

It seems `Uri` does not allow for escaped slashes `/` or dots `.`. Apparently this is for backward compatibility purposes. You can try the workaround mentioned on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12170132/1253041) which is backed by a solution by MS themselves on [this bug report on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/511010/erroneous-uri-parsing-for-encoded-reserved-characters-according-to-rfc-3986)

They suggest placing the following code in your `app.config` or `web.config` file:

```
<uri> 
    <schemeSettings> 
        <add name="http" genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes" /> 
    </schemeSettings> 
</uri>
```