# System.Uri and encoded colon (:)

Tags: c#, .net, uri, urlencode

Before .Net 4.5, it seems that System.Uri would unencode encoded slashes, but this has since been fixed. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20733619/188740

I'm encountering the same problem with colons. System.Uri still unencodes encoded colons.  Example:

```
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/?foo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com");
        var s = uri.ToString(); //http://www.example.com/?foo=http:%2F%2Fwww.example.com
```

Notice how `%3A` gets switched back to `:` by System.Uri. Is this a bug? What's the best workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `Uri.AbsoluteUri` instead?

```
var s = uri.AbsoluteUri; 
// http://www.example.com/?foo=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com
```

As per the source, `uri.ToString()` looks like it has logic to unescape certain parts which can be seen [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,1675) whereas `.AbsoluteUri` has a much simpler [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,738).

**Uri.ToString()**

As per the MSDN documentation for [`System.Uri.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx):

> A String instance that contains the unescaped canonical representation of the Uri instance. All characters are unescaped except #, ?, and %.

However as per the example and after trying out a few more strings, it looks like the actual implementation is somwhat like **'Only `:`, `*` and `spaces` are unescaped'**

```
%3A (:) // gets unescaped
%20 ( ) // gets unescaped 
%2A (*) // gets unescaped

%2b, %26, %23, %24, %25 (+, &, #, $, %) // Remain as-is (escaped)
```

Other Links

- [`System.Uri.AbsoluteUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: AbsoluteUri works like a charm. Why do colons get unencoded without AbsoluteUri? Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes looks like it. I believe the error is somewhere [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,1675) which goes ahead and unescapes certain parts. Whereas `.AbsoluteUri` has a much simpler [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/URI.cs,738).