# Cannot use WebClient.DownloadString when address variable include "/"

Tags: c#, jenkins, webclient, mstest, jenkins-mstest

i'm trying to send a request to my rabbitmq service in my automated tests, using WebClient object.

**code works perfectly on my local machine** when running tests in debug mode in visual studio.

when running tests in jenkins, using MSTest, web call returns 404. 
the reason is that url address includes a "/" char. 
i tried several options, as replacing this char with %2F and using system encoding. everything tried worked locally and failed miserably on build server

```
var headerValue = "XXX";
var url = "http://SERVER/api/exchanges/%2F/SOME/OTHER/INFO";
var req = new WebClient();
req.Headers["SOMEHEADER"] = headerValue;
var s = req.DownloadString(url);
```

looking for information about root cause for that phenomenon or solutions for this to work in jenkins

EDIT: this is not duplication of other questions since, as i mentions, code works perfectly on local machine, and the answers given in the other questions didn't helped solving the problem on remote server. [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781205/getting-a-url-with-an-url-encoded-slash)

Comment: `code works perfectly on my local machine` - in the IIS Express or the VS?

Comment: it is a tests project, so it works locally when run the tests in VS

Comment: Which web server is responding to your `WebClient`? It all comes down to how the web server handles the `//`, not your code. Your code incorrectly sends out a `//` like the duplicate shows (which I still believe to be a valid duplicate). You could verify it by applying the fix and seeing if it now works on your production server.

Comment: rabbitmq server.

any way, i worked around it and used EasyNetQ.Management.Client to make to api call.

thanks